# Probability condiioned on two variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Given random variables $X, Y, Z$, when does $p(X|Y, Z) = p(X|Y)p(X|Z)$?  Is such a transformation ever justified?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by $p(X|Y,Z)$, $p(X|Y)$ and $p(X|Z)$?

Comment: Do you mean $P(X|Y \cap Z) = P(X|Y)P(X|Z)$?

Answer (score 0):

> Almost never.

Let $p(x|y,z)=P(X=x\mid Y=y,Z=z)$, $q(x|y)=P(X=x\mid Y=y)$ and $r(x|z)=P(X=x\mid Z=z)$, then $\sum\limits_xq(x\mid y)=1$ and $r(x\mid z)\leqslant1$ for every $x$ hence $\sum\limits_xq(x\mid y)r(x\mid z)\leqslant1$ always and $\sum\limits_xq(x\mid y)r(x\mid z)\lt1$ most of the time.

On the other hand,  $\sum\limits_xp(x\mid y,z)=1$ hence the identity $p(x|y,z)=q(x|y)r(x|z)$ is quite unlikely.

*Exercise:* Determine the degenerate cases when, nevertheless, the equality holds.

Comment: Does $\sum_x q(x|y)r(x|z) = 1$ only when $x=z$?

Comment: What makes you think it should then?